# How to use a Fortran procedure pointer to take function name?

Tags: pointers, module, fortran, procedure

I'm trying to use a pointer procedure to select the function I need under a certain condition (in this case in a do loop).
Post a part of my code in which I show you what I intend to do.

! Main Program

```
program MKRBF

  use kernel
  use srbf

  implicit none

  !real*8 :: SelKer
  integer :: i,j,k
  integer, parameter :: n = 3
  integer, parameter :: nKer = 2
  real*8, dimension(2,2) :: ParBound, auxpar
  real*8, dimension(2) :: Bound
  real*8, dimension(n) :: Var, func
  real*8, dimension(n,nKer) :: coe
  real*8, dimension(n,n) :: mat

  !external SelKer
  pointer :: fp
  procedure(SelKer), pointer :: fp => null()

  Bound(1) = 0
  Bound(2) = 5

  ParBound(1,1) = 1 
  ParBound(1,2) = 5
  ParBound(2,1) = 1 
  ParBound(2,2) = 5

  auxpar(1,1) = 0 
  auxpar(1,2) = 0
  auxpar(2,1) = 1 
  auxpar(2,2) = 1

  var(:) = (/ 0., 2.5, 5. /)

  do i = 1, n
      func(i) = cos(3*Var(i)) * exp(-.25*Var(i));
  end do

  do i = 1, nKer
      fp => SelKer
      call weigth(n,Var,n,Var,1,func,fp(i),2.0D0,auxpar,coe,mat)
  end do
end program MKRBF
```

! Module testKernel.f90

```
module kernel
  implicit none
  contains

  ! POLYNOMIAL 
  function poly(x, ts, ndim, a, param1, param2)
    integer, intent (in) :: ndim
    real*8, dimension(ndim), intent(in) :: x
    real*8, dimension(ndim), intent(in) :: ts
    real*8, intent(in) :: a, param1, param2
    real*8 :: r
    real*8 :: poly 

    r = sqrt(sum((x(1:ndim) - ts(1:ndim))**2.))

    poly = r**a

  end function poly

  ! GAUSSIAN
  function gauss(x, ts, ndim, a, gamma, param2)
     integer, intent (in) :: ndim 
     real*8, dimension(ndim), intent(in) :: x
     real*8, dimension(ndim), intent(in) :: ts
     real*8, intent(in) :: a, param2, gamma
     real*8 :: r
     real*8 :: gauss

     r = sqrt(sum((x(1:ndim) - ts(1:ndim))**2.))

    gauss = exp(-(gamma*r)**a)

 end function gauss

 function SelKer(indx) 
   integer, intent(in) :: indx
   real*8 :: SelKer

   select case (indx)
   case (1)
     SelKer => poly
   case (2)
     SelKer => gauss
   end select
 end function SelKer

end module kernel
```

! Module testSRBF.f90

```
module srbf
 implicit none
 contains  

 subroutine weigth(nx, x, nts, ts, ndim, s, kernel, StocPar, param, coe, mat)
   integer :: i,j,k,l,m,n
   integer :: info
   integer :: nx, nts, ndim
   integer, dimension(nts) :: ipiv 
   real*8, dimension(nts) :: w
   real*8, dimension(nts) :: s
   real*8, dimension(2) :: param
   real*8, dimension(nx,ndim) :: x
   real*8, dimension(nts,ndim) :: ts
   real*8, dimension(nx,nts) :: phi, mat
   real*8, dimension(nts) :: coe
   real*8 :: stocPar

   interface
    real*8 function kernel(x1, x2, n3, stov, p1, p2)
      integer, intent (in) :: n3
      real*8, dimension(n3), intent(in) :: x1
      real*8, dimension(n3), intent(in) :: x2
      real*8, intent(in) :: stov, p1, p2
    end function kernel
   end interface

   do i = 1, nx
     do j = 1, nts
         phi(i,j) = kernel(x(i,1:ndim), ts(j,1:ndim), ndim, stocPar, param(1), param(2))
     end do
   end do

   w = s       
   mat = phi   
   call DGESV(nts,1,mat,nts,ipiv,w,nts,info) 
   coe = w
 end subroutine weigth 
end module srbf
```

This gives the compilation error

```
testKer_mod.f90:41:20: SelKer => poly
Error: Function 'poly' requires an argument list at (1)
```

and the same for the other function.

Comment: Which aspect of this is causing problems?  Do you get a compiler/runtime error or message, or wrong results, other something else?  What I do note, though, is that you likely don't want `fp=>Selker`, but `fp=>SelKer(i)` (that is, you want to point to the function result, not the function itself).

Comment: Compilation error is: testKer_mod.f90:41:20: SelKer => poly Error: Function 'poly' requires an argument list at (1), and the same for the other function.

Comment: I want to pass only the name of the function because its evaluation takes place in testSRBF_mod.f90

Comment: Why are you using the totally non-standard real*8 in what otherwise looks very clean code. I strongly suggest you use the kind mechanism, as defined by the Fortran standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the function `SelKer`:

```
function SelKer(indx) 
  integer, intent(in) :: indx
  real*8 :: SelKer

  select case (indx)
  case (1)
    SelKer => poly
  case (2)
    SelKer => gauss
  end select
end function SelKer
```

Here `poly` and `gauss` are intended to be the module procedures we've defined.

The function result `SelKer` has been declared to be a `real*8` scalar non-pointer value.  It isn't a procedure pointer.  To declare the function result as a procedure pointer, with interface `poly` (noting that `poly` and `gauss` have the same characteristics):

```
procedure(poly), pointer :: SelKer
```

With this change the pointer assignment statements in the `select case` construct are now valid: the function result points to the corresponding function.

That said, there are other parts to address in the body of the question.  Look now at

```
pointer :: fp
procedure(SelKer), pointer :: fp => null()
```

along with

```
fp => SelKer
call weigth(n,Var,n,Var,1,func,fp(i),2.0D0,auxpar,coe,mat)
```

The first block has a problem: you can't specify the pointer attribute for `fp` twice.  Remove the line `pointer :: fp`.

Using `fp` to point always to `SelKer` is also redundant: you may as well just write

```
call weigth(n,Var,n,Var,1,func,Selker(i),2.0D0,auxpar,coe,mat)
```

and not have `fp` as a procedure pointer.  The more useful use of `fp` as a procedure pointer would be

```
procedure(poly), pointer :: fp=>null
...
do i = 1, nKer
  fp => SelKer(i)
  call weigth(n,Var,n,Var,1,func,fp,2.0D0,auxpar,coe,mat)
end do
```

Comment: Hi @francescalus , thanks for the reply. I did what you have posted, but the program keeps giving me compilation errors.

Comment: I inserted 'procedure(poly), pointer :: SelKer' in the select case instead of 'SelKer => poly' and made the changes in the main as you advised me. However it gives me this compilation error:  
    'testKer_mod.f90:42:6:
       procedure(poly), pointer :: SelKer
      1
    Error: Unclassifiable statement at (1)'

Comment: The `procedure(poly), pointer :: SelKer` is to replace `real*8 :: SelKer` (outside the select case).